# Convenience constructor with generics callback will crash in Swift 3.1

Tags: swift, generics, swift3, crash

When creating a child class object which extends the generic base class, if it is created using convenience constructor, a callback contains the generic object will crash in the runtime because of the incorrect/corrupted object being passed back. 
It is new in Swift3.1. There is no such problem in Swift 3.0.
It only happens when creating an object using convenience constructor.

```
protocol Initializable {
    init()
}

class MyClass: Initializable {
    required init() {}
    func log() {
        print("Hello")
    }
}

class Parent<T: Initializable> {
    typealias Callback = (T) -> Void

    init(callback: Callback) {
        callback(T())
    }
}

class Child: Parent<MyClass> {
    convenience init(value: Int, callback: Callback) {
        self.init(callback: callback)
    }
    override init(callback: Callback) {
        super.init(callback: callback)
    }
}

let _ = Child { data in
    data.log() //This is OK
}

let _ = Child(value: 0) { data in
    data.log() //This will crash under swift3.1
}
```

Is it a language bug? Or am I doing something not supposed to be?